How can I fix this advancement in modded minecraft?
There is an advancement in skyfactory 4 where you have to fill a cookie jar with cookies.
setTitle("Who Stole the Cookies from the Cookie Jar?")

setIcon(<bibliocraft:cookiejar>)

//setDescription("Fill a Cookie Jar with Cookies and Right-Click it!")

setDescription({"translate":"advancement.sf4.age_allthethingsomglol.cookie.description","with":[{"keybind":"key.use"}]})

addParent("sf4:age_allthethingsomglol/root")

//Criteria
criteria = addCriteria("Right Click Filled Cookie Jar", "triumph:right_click_block")
criteria.setBlock(<bibliocraft:cookiejar, tile:{cookiecount:8,names:["item.cookie","item.cookie","item.cookie","item.cookie","item.cookie","item.cookie","item.cookie","item.cookie"],Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:cookie",Count:64b,Damage:0s},{Slot:1b,id:"minecraft:cookie",Count:64b,Damage:0s},{Slot:2b,id:"minecraft:cookie",Count:64b,Damage:0s},{Slot:3b,id:"minecraft:cookie",Count:64b,Damage:0s},{Slot:4b,id:"minecraft:cookie",Count:64b,Damage:0s},{Slot:5b,id:"minecraft:cookie",Count:64b,Damage:0s},{Slot:6b,id:"minecraft:cookie",Count:64b,Damage:0s},{Slot:7b,id:"minecraft:cookie",Count:64b,Damage:0s}]}>)    
b
//Rewards
setRewardExperience(60)

hideLines()
alwaysVisible()
setPos(-79,51)

I have tried to change biliocraft:cookiejar to minecraft:cookiejar and I get the advancment, but I get it without there being cookies in the jar but just when I place it down.
